# How to display the non-existing value fields in the queried result of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

When I tried to use SQL to query the non-existing fields in time series of Apache IoTDB, why these fields are not displayed in the columns of the result sets? How can I set these non-existing fields to be displayed in the result queried and make its value to be `null`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `create timeseries` command in Apache IoTDB to create a time series with these non-existing fields, then these fields will appear in the query results and the values will be `null`.